# Can someone identify this spider?

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

Saw this on the street in the UK. To my eyes it looked and moved distinctly tarantula-y (although I don't have any firsthand experience with them) which I'm pretty sure we don't have any of natively. Most of the spiders you commonly see here are thinner generally and move much faster. This guy lumbered.

For scale, it didn't span more than a couple of inches.

[image]

Comment: That is a kind of [orb weaver](http://bugguide.net/node/view/1015808/bgimage).

Comment: @Charles Did you want to post this as an answer? Having researched more thoroughly, I think you probably linked the exact species.

Comment: Yes, the species that I suggested, *Araneus diadematus*, is most likely the correct ID. And yes, I suppose I can turn this into an answer. Originally that day I had already provided an ID for someone else that was of an orb weaver, and so, I was giving someone else a chance to ID. Since it's been a few days and still nobody has seized the opportunity, I'll provide an answer within the next few hours. Thanks for following up. :)